# Timeline for Visual Studio Lightswitch RC / RTM

Tags: .net, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

Does anybody know if there is already a RC / RTM **Timeline** for **Visual Studio Lightswitch** ? When can we expect **V1.0** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just announced... July 26, 2011

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](http://rcpmag.com/articles/2011/03/15/lightswitch-beta-2-at-ms-dev-partner-summit.aspx):

> According to Dave Mendlen, senior
>   director of developer marketing at
>   Microsoft, the final shipping version
>   of LightSwitch will be released "later
>   this year."

Of course, beta 2 release is provided with a Go Live license which you can get more information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/03/15/visual-studio-lightswitch-beta-2-released-with-go-live-license.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps, but the current release, Beta 2, has a "Go Live" license.

(I know this does not answer the question, but I figured it might help answer the spirit of the question)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have not yet released any details with regards to the RTM release date. According to the following thread, there will not be an RC release of LightSwitch. The next release will be RTM.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/thread/9ac29f15-9d2f-498a-b8a2-764179818dc7

The beta 2 license agreement states that the software will expire on the 11th October 2011. Given this information, you might be able to make some assumption as to broadly when to expect RTM to be released.